# KnockoutJs - Get updated value from view in ViewModel

Tags: asp.net, knockout.js

I'm new to KnockoutJs and I'm trying to use it with ASP.net webforms in a .ascx.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s7wJ9/)

The View

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="button" data-bind="click: addNewRow" style="-moz-border-bottom-colors: blue" value="Add More Lines" />
        <input type="button" data-bind="click: addToCart" style="-moz-border-bottom-colors: blue" value="Add Items to Cart" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Product Number</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
</tr>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: quickEntries">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input data-bind="text: $data.ItemPartNumb(), onkeyup: showValue" class="ItemPartNum" height="100" width="500" /> 
        </td>
        <td>
            <input data-bind="text: $data.ItemDescription()" class="ItemDescr" height="100" width="500" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input data-bind="text: $data.ItemQuanties()" class="ItemQuan" height="100" width="500" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

The ViewModel

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var QuickEntry = function (_itemPartNumb, _itemDescription, _itemQuanities) {
    this.ItemPartNumb = ko.observable(_itemPartNumb);
    this.ItemDescription = ko.observable(_itemDescription);
    this.ItemQuanties = ko.observable(_itemQuanities);
};

function QuickEntriesViewModel() {

    var self = this;
    self.quickEntries = ko.observableArray([]);

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        self.quickEntries.push(new QuickEntry('Bob','Jack','Steve'));            
    }

    self.addNewRow = function() {
        self.quickEntries.push(new QuickEntry());
    };

    self.showValue = function(quickEntry) {
        alert(quickEntry.ItemPartNumb); //Nothing show
    };

    self.addToCart = function () {
        //Error here. How do i access the obserablearray?
        alert(self.quickEntries.length);
    };

};

//This is where you bind the ViewModel
ko.applyBindings(new QuickEntriesViewModel());
```

The web page will started out with 10 empty QuickEntry and user can add more line. It created a table for me with 10 empty rows. After user enter some info into the table such as item part number, description...etc. I'll take those info and call web api POST method. When I try to accsee the quickEntries observablesarray. I got nothing/undefined and when I try onkeyup. There is no pop-up to show me the new value.

Isn't element bounded to a observable will auto update its value? How do I get the observable array values within the ViewModel once its value is changed?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please put your code in a JSFiddle? (http://jsfiddle.net) [It just makes it easier to see what you're trying to do.] Also, your `self.addNewRow` method is simply adding an empty `QuickEntry` to your observable array. That's probably the root of your problem.

Comment: I've added JSFiddle. What I want to do is start out with a table with 10 empty QuickEntry so user can type into the table then if they need more item. They can click on addNewRow to the table. Thanks.

Comment: Here is a working fiddle back: http://jsfiddle.net/s7wJ9/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
self.quickEntries()
```

Will return the underlying array with all its glorious data

Comment: You're correct. I found that out yesterday. You have to treat it as function.